# After else statement catches invalid input valid input isn't accepted

Tags: python, python-2.7

After the else statement catches invalid input and advises the user of this any input after this is caught as invalid input even when the input should be valid. Also, I'm very new to Python so any suggestions on the rest of the code would be appreciated. Below is the code I have written:

```
from __future__ import division #Allows for division to return a float value
from colorama import init,Fore,Style,Back #Allows for formating color and stylizing text output to terminal screen
init(convert=True) #Allows Colorama to work on Windows 10 machine
import os

running=True

def printAnswer(sign,userInput1,userInput2,answer):
    "Prints the formated answer to the screen"
    print
    print Fore.RED, Style.BRIGHT,userInput1, sign, userInput2, "=", answer, "\n" #Changes text to red
    print Style.RESET_ALL #Changes text back to normal from Red
    try:
        input= raw_input("Press any key to continue")
    except NameError:
        pass

def printAnswerRemainder(sign,userInput1,userInput2,answerInt,remainder):
    "Prints the formated division answer with remainder"
    print Fore.Red, Style.BRIGHT, "\n", userInput2, sign, userInput1, "=", answerInt," Remainder ", remainder, "\n" #Changes text color to red
    print Style.RESET_All #Resets text color back to normal


def newAdd(userInput1,userInput2):
    "Performs the addition function"
    sign="+"
    answer=userInput1+userInput2
    printAnswer(sign,userInput1,userInput2,answer)

def newSub(userInput1,userInput2):
    "Performs the Subtraction function"
    sign="-"
    answer=userInput1-userInput2
    printAnswer(sign,userInput1,userInput2,answer)

def newDivision(userInput1, userInput2):
    "Performs divsion function giving a decimal answer and an answer with the remainder"
    sign="/"
    answer=userInput2/userInput1
    answerInt=userInput2//userInput1
    remainder=userInput2%userInput1
    printAnswerRemainder(sign,userInput1,userInput2,answerInt,remainder)
    printAnswer(sign, userInput2, userInput1, answer)


def newMult(userInput1,userInput2):
    sign="X"
    answer=userInput1*userInput2
    printAnswer(sign,userInput1,userInput2,answer)

while running==True: 
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') #Clears the terminal of previous activity
    userSelect=raw_input("Please enter the number of the type of operation you would like to complete:\n\t 1.Addition\n\t 2.Subtraction\n\t 3.Division\n\t 4.Multiplication\n\t 5.Exit\n\n-------> ")

    if userSelect=="1":
        addNum1=input("Enter the first number to add:\n")
        addNum2=input("Enter the second nummebr to add:\n")
        newAdd(addNum1,addNum2)

    elif userSelect=="2":
        subNum1=input("Enter the number to subtract from: \n")
        subNum2=input("Enter the number you would like to subtract: \n")
        newSub(subNum1,subNum2)

    elif userSelect=="3":
        divNum1=input("Enter the dividend: \n")
        divNum2=input("Enter the divisor: \n")
        newDivision(divNum2,divNum1)
    elif userSelect=="4":
        multNum1=input("Enter the number that is being multiplied: \n")
        multNum2=input("Enter the number to be multiplied by: \n")
        newMult(multNum1,multNum2)
    elif userSelect=="5":
        running=False
    **else:
        print "The command was invalid"
        try:
            input= raw_input("Press any key to continue")
        except NameError:
            pass**
```

Answer (score 1):

In this else clause, you are overwriting the build-in function `input`:

```
    try:
        input= raw_input("Press any key to continue")
```

Instead, this should work fine:

```
    try:
        anykey = raw_input("Press any key to continue")
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you for the response. I understand the reason now and can avoid it in the future.